# MIPS assembly language

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to write the MIPS assembly language that prompt the user to input two number describing two dimensions of a system screen, expressed in pixels, and then calculates and prints the pixel count of the screen.

for example, in c++:

```
int width,height,result;
cout<<"Enter width of the device screen: ";
cin>>width;
cout<<"Enter height of the device screen: ";
cout>>height;
result=width*height;
cout<<"The result of the Iphone 4S in pixel: "<<result;
```

(this is my first time write this MIPS assembly, so I am sure this code is wrong. I need someone to help me correct this codes below and explain to me please. )

```
.data
str1: .asciiz "Enter width of the device screen: "
str2: .asciiz "Enter height of the device screen: "
str3: .asciiz "The result of the Iphone 4S in pixel: "
newline: .asciiz "\n"

main:
li $v0,4 #system call code for print string
la $a0,str1 #address of str1
syscall #print str1

#get the first number from the user, put into $s0
li $v0,5 #system call for read input
syscall #read integer into $v0 from console.
move $s0,$v0 #move the number read into $s0

#read input string for str2
li $v0,4  #system call code for print string
la $a0,str2 #address of str2
syscall #print str2

#get the second number from the user, put into $s1
li $v0,5 #system call for read input
syscall #read integer into $v0 from console.
move $s1,$v0 #move the number read into $s0

#do the calculation 
mul $s2,$s0,$s1 # s2 is the register to store $s0 and $s1 from the user input.

#read print string for st3
li $v0,4 #system call code for print string

#print width*height
li $v0,1
move $ao,$s2 #move the result of multiplication into $a0 to print
syscall
```

Comment: What's your question? With which part are you having trouble?

Answer (score 1):

Your program is pretty close - you just have a couple of problems:

1. You're missing a `.text` directive.  That should probably go after your `newline` line and before `main:`.
2. You have a `$ao` where you probably want a `$a0` near the end of the program.
3. You didn't ever print `str3` - you need to add:

   ```
   la $a0,str3 #address of str3
   syscall
   ```

   after your `li $v0,4 #system call code for print string` line.
4. You should make sure to add an `exit` syscall at the end of your program:

   ```
   li $v0,10
   syscall
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
.data
str1: .asciiz "Enter width of the device screen: "
str2: .asciiz "Enter height of the device screen: "
str3: .asciiz "The result of the Iphone 4S in pixel: "
newline: .asciiz "\n"
         .text 

main:
li $v0,4                       #system call code for print string
la $a0,str1                    #address of str1
syscall                        #print str1

                               #get the first number from the user, put into $s0
li $v0,5 #system call for read input
syscall #read integer into $v0 from console.
move $s0,$v0 #move the number read into $s0

#read input string for str2
li $v0,4  #system call code for print string
la $a0,str2 #address of str2
syscall #print str2

#get the second number from the user, put into $s1
li $v0,5 #system call for read input
syscall #read integer into $v0 from console.
move $s1,$v0 #move the number read into $s0

#do the calculation 
mul $s2,$s0,$s1 # s2 is the register to store $s0 and $s1 from the user input.

#read print string for st3
li $v0,4 #system call code for print string
la $a0, str3
syscall
#print width*height
li $v0,1
move $a0,$s2 #move the result of multiplication into $a0 to print
syscall
#
li $v0, 10
syscall
```